# CSS selector based on classes

Tags: css

I generally like working with CSS selectors but there is one specific case that I don't understand, and also references like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) don't help me to solve this issue.

Let's say this is my code:

```css
.zero .one:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="zero">
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="zero">
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="zero">
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div>Okay!</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
</div>
```

I select `.zero .one:nth-child(2)` what means in my understanding that every second child with the class `.one` of a `.zero` container gets selected. But in this case it takes the first and not the second `<div class="one">Lol</div>` of each `.zero` container.

The question would be: How can I select every second `<div class="one">Lol</div>` of each `.zero` container?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of what I found, but I also gave an answer, since you have a particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:nth-child(n)` won't be of any-help here and  `:nth-class(n)` does not exist as far as i know.

What you could do is to use the ~ selector, and use it twice to do a reset , no matter the structure:

example

```css
.zero .one~.one {/* look for any class one standing somewhere after class one */
  color: red;
}

.zero .one~.one~.one {/* now if we find a third one or more; lets reset it */
  color: initial;
}


/* only for layout demo purpose, not relevant for the question */
div[class]:before {
  content: 'My class is: ' attr(class);
  color: green;
  background: yellow;
  padding-inline: 0.5em;
  margin: inline-end:1em;
}

.zero {
  background: lightgray;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10em, 1fr));
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="zero">
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
</div>
<div class="zero">
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
</div>
<div class="zero">
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="two">loL</div><!-- it can be no class or another in the way, does not matter -->
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
</div>
<div class="zero">
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't test this, but will it work with the other use case - where the classless `div` elements are not next to each other?

Comment: @disinfor , examples shows them not next to each others, it is the purpose of the `~`selector, find if any somewhere behind instead right behind ;) To test, just run the snippet

Comment: Oh, sure enough, you snuck a `two` class in there. +1. I edited the answer and gave an upvote. This is great.

Comment: Since you edited it back in, I think it would be good to add a classless version like OPs code as well, since I missed the `two` class that was added - and I assume others will as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix in this way for your case

```
.zero .one:nth-child(2n+1) {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
.zero .one:nth-child(2n+1) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="zero">
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="zero">
  <div>Bla bla bla</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
  <div class="one">Lol</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP doesn't want every `2n` instance...just the second element with the class `.one`